# Mutually exclusive elements based upon the radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to toggle en-ability/disability of two form fields based upon the radio button selections. Not Happening. Have a look and please tell me which part of my cerebral cortex needs to be developed. - http://jsfiddle.net/KggHA/3/ . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function initPopupInputsEffect() {
    if ($('input[name=ruleType]:checked').val() == "Banana") {
        $("#AppleBoat").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#BananaBoat").attr('disabled', false);
    }
    else { 
        $("#BananaBoat").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#AppleBoat").attr('disabled', false);
    }
}​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/KggHA/4/)**

You need to look for the :checked radio button, and then set the disabled attribute to true or false accordingly rather than removing it.

Comment: Thank you sir. May a plethora of gold badges make their way through to you by days end.